# Handle multiple connections in Flask API

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a simple internal REST API for our solution using Flask, serving JSON objects through get calls (including authentication). We have multiple backends to fetch data from. From what I understand these should be connected to in a function decorated with `@app.before_request` and assigned to the `g` global for use in the specific route being requested. It's not a pattern I'm used to.

Here is a toy example of what I'm doing:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.some_conn_a = create_connection('a')
    g.some_conn_b = create_connection('b')
    g.some_client = create_client()


@app.route('/get_some_data')
@requires_auth
def get_some_data():
    # Fetch something from all connections in g
    payload = ... # Construct payload using above connections
    return jsonify(payload)


@app.route('/get_some_other_data')
@requires_auth
def get_some_other_data():
    # Fetch something from maybe just g.some_conn_b
    payload = ... # Construct payload using g.some_conn_b
    return jsonify(payload)
```

This seems wasteful to me if the user makes a request for data residing in only one or two of these connections/clients, like in the `get_some_other_data` route example.

I'm considering just making the connections/clients in the route functions instead, or load it lazily. What's the "correct" way? I hope it isn't to make a new module, that seems extreme for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riffing on [the Flask docs Database Connections example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/dbcon/) 
you could modify **get_db()** to accept an argument for each of your multiple connections.

```
def get_db(conn):
    """Open specificied connection if none yet for the current app context. """
    if conn == 'some_conn_a':
        if not hasattr(g, 'some_conn_a'):
            g.some_conn_a = create_connection('a')
        db = g.some_conn_a
    elif conn == 'some_conn_b':
        if not hasattr(g, 'some_conn_b'):
            g.some_conn_b = create_connection('b')
        db = g.some_conn_b 
    elif conn == 'some_client':
        if not hasattr(g, 'some_client'):
            g.some_client = create_client()
        db = g.some_client
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown connection: %s" % conn)

    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    """Closes the db connections. """
    if hasattr(g, 'some_conn_a'):
        g.some_conn_a.close()
    if hasattr(g, 'some_conn_b'):
        g.some_conn_b.close()
    if hasattr(g, 'some_client'):
        g.some_client.close()
```

Then you could query each connection as needed:

```
@app.route('/get_some_data')
def get_some_data():
    data_a = get_db('some_conn_a').query().something()
    data_b = get_db('some_conn_b').query().something()
    data_c = get_db('some_client').query().something()
    payload = {'a': data_a, 'b': data_b, 'c': data_c}
    return jsonify(payload)
```

The *get_db()* pattern is preferred over the *before_request* pattern for lazy loading database connections. The docs examples for Flask 0.11 and up utilize the *get_db()* pattern to a larger extent.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. A question: If the *before_request* decorator isn't recommended for connections, why is it in the tutorial? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/dbcon/ **Ninja edit**: Ah. The example is older than your example. So things have changed since I worked with it last.

Comment: Alright. I've look into it more now. Your recommendation seems to be aligned with my initial thoughts about loading it lazily from the routing function. This also makes more sense to me. The additional step is to assign the connection `g` as soon as it's created, so that we can close it in *teardown_appcontext*. I'm fine with this. Thanks.